# How to fit Smooth Overlap of Atomic Positions (SOAP) into Kernel Ridge Regression (KRR)?

Tags: computational-chemistry, python, machine-learning

I have a dataset of 64 chemical structures and their calculated energies, which I want to predict using machine learning. I need to use SOAP as a descriptor so that each structure would be an individual descriptor, and each descriptor is a matrix (according to the documentation) where each row represents the local environment of one atom of the molecule. So the 'shape' of these descriptors would be *(number of atoms x number of features)* if I understand correctly.
Currently, I have a list of descriptors with a length of 64 (the number of structures in the system) for each structure, but I'm having problems fitting this list into the KRR model. As far as I understand, the descriptors list has the following structure: (simplified)

```
descriptors = [
# 1st structure 
   [
      [ ... ] # atoms features
      [ ... ] # atoms features
      ... up to the number of atoms in the structure 
   ]
# 2nd structure
   [
      [ ... ] # atoms features
      [ ... ] # atoms features
      ... up to the number of atoms in the structure
   ]
   ...
]
```

Each row (atom) has the same number of features. The structures have different numbers of atoms.
Is there a better way to process this dataset so I can fit this into KRR? The KRR accepts input of shape *(n_samples, n_features)*, so I imagined that would be (64, n_features), but how to correctly reshape this into such structure? I'm very new to this so any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: We don't know if all 64 structures have the same number of atoms. If not they should be padded so that they do. Also, the input to KRR is a matrix $(N_{examples}, M_{feats})$, so if your data structure is a vector of matrices $(N_{examples}, L_{atoms}, M_{feats})$, you should reshape it so that it becomes a matrix $(N_{examples}, L_{atoms} \cdot M_{feats})$. Finally, you should be careful with the maths of the kernel function, which is supposed to give you a similarity matrix between examples, essentially. If you reshape, check that the maths makes sense.

Comment: Thank you, I edited the question. The structures do not have the same number of atoms.

Comment: @Anon Thank you so much. I did exactly what you mentioned, and it works now! I think the key thing I was missing was realizing that they need to have the same number of atoms. After adding the padding, the structure had three dimensions (exactly as you mentioned), but KRR expects two, so the reshaping afterward was expected. Again, thank you so much. It was very helpful. I'm gonna double-check the math and the different values for parameters, but it is finally working! :)

Comment: nice, happy that it helped. Be careful to check that the kernel function operates only on the attributes of each atom. Besides, I don't know what kernel you are using, but for SOAP I believe there was something like a cosine similarity kernel suggested by Bartok, Csanyi etc (the inventors of SOAP).

Finally, if you allow me a bit of skepticism on your numbers, 64 examples really is a tiny data set. I hope that you have a pre-trained model on a much larger data set. Otherwise, if 64 examples is all you have, maybe you should think of alternatives to ML.

Comment: @Anon Thank you, I will look into it. I have been doing some hyper-parameter tuning for both the KRR and the SOAP and was able to achieve some promising results. This is actually part of my Master's thesis, and I'm planning to use Gradient Boosting as well as neural networks and compare these results. Yeah, it is not a very large dataset, I think in total, there were about 4100 atoms. I'm cooperating with a chemical institute that provides the dataset, they calculate the energies with DFT by themselves. I'm hoping they gather more data eventually.

Comment: Nice, @jessss, good job on your Master's work then! If the data set is small, KRR or XGB are definitely better than NNs, which have way too many parameters and the risk of overfitting is serious. Keep it up!

Comment: @Anon thank you! I have one more question about this topic, if you don't mind me asking. The second part of my work is to do the same but predict atomic forces. I have essentially the same dataset (same structure - atoms in structures, each has x y z coordinates), and each atom has its atomic forces (x,y,z) calculated. I'm unsure of the correct approach here, i.e., calculating SOAP descriptors for the structures/atoms in the structures and how it would differ from creating descriptors for the whole structure since SOAP creates representation for each atom in the structure.

Comment: Hi @jessss, no worries. When you want to predict forces it's not your input that changes, but your output. When you had to compute energies, the output of the KRR model would be a vector of shape $N_{examples}$. Now, with forces, the output must be $(N_{examples}, L_{atoms}, 3)$. That's it!
Depending on how your code works, you might want as output a matrix of shape $(N_{examples}, L_{atoms} \cdot 3)$, which you can reshape after the calculation in a more easily interpretable shape.

Comment: Hi @Anon thank you again, It works how you explained it! I hope I assumed correctly that it is also necessary to add padding for the atomic forces to match the number of atoms in the structures after padding them as well. Afterward, the process was quite similar to predicting energies with the reshaping, and the shape also intuitively makes sense. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Happy you found my points clear and that they helped. Good luck with the rest of the work!

Comment: Hi @Anon it's been some time! I have been trying to make the forces work with KRR, but unfortunately, I can't reach any decent results. The numbers are quite off, and I tried applying PCA, some transformations, and normalization... I was wondering if you're familiar with some approaches to predicting atomic forces. A small fraction of the results: `Predicted atomic forces: [[-0.000067774  0.000056601 -0.000148269 ...` & `Actual atomic forces: [[-0.001675992 -0.000534207  0.002661466...` I am using a similar approach with energies, and they're working well so far.

Comment: Hi @jessss, good to hear from you again. I don't have any suggestion occurring to me after your message. The things I would do are, in this order, computing derivatives of the model predicting energies, increase the data set and try all this again, change algorithm. I can't help you much without knowing details.

Comment: @Anon My math is really rusty, but yes, I was using two separate models, but now I am thinking about a single model, that takes into consideration that forces are described as derivative of the energy, and compute corresponding derivative of the model. I think fundamentally I am missing something here, so I will have to deep dive more into the relationship between energy and forces and the respective calculations. I am much more computer scientist and much less a chemist haha, I do really appreciate your inputs, though, since I haven't been able to find much help elsewhere.

Comment: The forces are the negative of the gradient of the energies wrt nuclear positions. If you are using KRR, the derivatives of the KRR prediction with respect to the input are analytical. You need to write some maths to derive your input wrt nuclear positions and apply the chain rule. Sorry, I assumed you were a chemist. Also, it can be a good idea to implement all this in frameworks providing automatic differentiation.